# Fundamental group of a space under a group action

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, group-actions, fundamental-groups

The short version:

> Why does a Borcea-Voisin threefold has trivial fundamental group?

Well, what *is* a Borcea-Voisin threefold? These are named after Borcea and Voisin, who introduced a method of constructing Calabi-Yau threefolds from elliptic curves (CY-onefolds) and K3 surfaces (CY-twofolds), and going through Voisin's proof that these threefolds are indeed Calabi-Yau, I'm stuck on why the fundamental group is trivial.

In detail, let $E$ be an elliptic curve with canonical involution $(x,y)\mapsto (x,-y)$ (we're working in characteristic $0$). Let $S$ be a K3 surface with (non-symplectic) involution $\sigma$ acting by $-1$ on $H^{2,0}(S)$. Then the (crepant) resolution of $E\times S/\iota\times\sigma$ is a Calabi-Yau threefold. Denote the resolution by $X$.

To see this, there are a few things to show (though I'm happy with showing the necessary Hodge numbers are zero, once $\pi_1(X)$ is trivial). Firstly, we can write the resolution $X$ as $\widetilde{E\times S}/\widetilde{\iota\times\sigma}$, where we blowup the fixed locus of $\iota\times\sigma$ on $E\times S$, then extend the action of $\iota\times\sigma$.

The fixed locus of an elliptic curve under the involution is four isolated points (topological Lefschetz trace) and the fixed locus of $S$ under $\sigma$ is the union of (say) $N$ disjoint curves (holomorphic and topological Lefschetz trace). Thus, the fixed locus of $E\times S$ is the union of each $P_i\times C_j$, where each $P_i$ is an isolated (fixed) point on $E$ and $C_j$ is a (fixed) curve on $S$.

If there is at least one fixed curve $C$ on $S$, there is at least one fixed point on $E\times S$, say $P$, and $\widetilde{\iota\times\sigma}$ acts on the fundamental group $\pi_1(\widetilde{E\times S},P)$ by $-1$, as
$$ \pi_1(\widetilde{E\times S},P) \simeq \pi_1(E\times S,P) \simeq \pi_1(E)\times\pi_1(S) \simeq \pi_1(E), $$
and the action of $\iota$ on $E$ passes through to $\pi_1(E)$.

Voisin now claims this implies $\pi_1(X)$ is trivial, and I'm guessing it shouldn't be too difficult to justify, given there are no details, but I'm not too sure how this is done. I've also asked a few people that know far more about the fundamental group than I do, and no one had a solution (though they all say it's probably simple...)

I'd love to just say
$$ \pi_1(X/G) \simeq \pi_1(X)^G, $$
for any $X$ with action by $G$, but this isn't always true...

Is there something horribly simple I've missed for this case? Thanks!

Comment: The thing you'd love to just say confuses me. For example, if $X$ is nice and, in particular, simply connected and the action of $G$ is nice and, in particular, free then $\pi_1(X/G) \cong G$. So the thing you wrote instead doesn't seem like the obvious conjecture to make.

Comment: Oh, sorry if I was unclear @QiaochuYuan, that's not much of a conjecture, as I know it's false in general. However, in Voisin's article, she says that $\widetilde{\iota\times\sigma}$ acts on $\pi_1(\widetilde{E\times S})$ by $-1$, and hence the fundamental group of the quotient is trivial. I don't see how that follows, but the action by minus 1 has no nontrivial fixed points, and I don't see how else the implication might follow... The idea is just (naively) trying to mimic cohomology of the quotient being the fixed part

Comment: I do not know anything about the subject, but there is a general theorem: Suppose that $\Gamma$ is a group acting properly discontinuously on a simply-connected space $Z$ (say,  a simplicial complex) and $\Gamma$ generated by elements each of which has nonempty fixed-point set in $X$. Then $\pi_1(Z/Gamma)$ is trivial. In your setting, I would try to lift the action of $G$ to the universal cover and consider the group $\Gamma$ generated by the lift and the group of deck-transformations. Then see if you can show that $\Gamma$ is generated by elements with nonempty fixed point sets.

Comment: Hm, I don't know if that will quite work in this case. The elliptic curve $E = \mathbb{C}/\Lambda$ for some lattice $\Lambda$, so the covering space of $E\times S$ would be $\mathbb{C}\times S$ with the action of $\iota\times \sigma$ lifting with the action of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ coming from $\Lambda$, which is translation, so shouldn't have any fixed points...

Comment: However, your mention of deck transformations may make quick work of it... the group of deck transformations for the universal cover of $E\times S$ is isomorphic to $\pi_1(E\times S)$, and then taking the quotient and looking at
the deck transformations for this larger (universal) cover, where the involutions acted by $-1$ on $\pi_1(E\times S)$ (i.e., the previous group of deck transformations) kills the deck transformations upstairs, so the fundamental group is trivial.

Comment: (@studiosus forgot to tag..) though actually, upon taking the quotient, one would need to look at the orbifold fundamental group, though I think this still works...

Comment: @Alex: This is the ordinary fundamental group. In terms of orbifolds: $\pi_1(O)=\pi_1^{orb}(O)/N$, where $N$ is the normal subgroup generated by elements with nonempty fixed point sets. Here $\pi_1$ is the usual fundamental group and $\pi_1^{orb}$ is the orbifold fundamental group.

Comment: @studiosus, alright, chatting with my smart colleagues some more, we may have come across the elementary solution. We can actually try to "construct" loops on the quotient. They're either coming from upstairs (and these get killed by the quotient) or they're appearing after the quotient. However, our base point was a fixed point, so any loop about it lifts to a loop in $\widetilde{E\times S}$ (which was killed by the quotient).

This actually seems like the approach she had in mind.